# Run actions while jquery .animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this little piece of code to make the browser scroll to top:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 500, "easeOutQuart");
```

And I want to disable the user scrolling while this code is running, and enable it again when the animation ends. How would you do that? What's the best way to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable it just **before** the animation call, and enable it in the callback option of [animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) :

```
//Disable here

$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 500, "easeOutQuart", function() {
    //enable here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the scrollbar for a while and then again enable that

```
 var htmlBody = $('html, body');
 htmlBody.css("overflow","hidden")
         .animate({
             scrollTop: 0
          }, 500, "easeOutQuart",function(){
                htmlBody.css("overflow","auto");
          });
```

Check this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Uh8Hs/)